# UseStaticFiles OnPrepareResponse switching stream at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to replace the original image stream with another image stream?

It seems I am unable to assign sr to HttpResponse

Using asp core 2

Is it possible to do this or is there any other way to do it?

```
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = x =>
                {   
                    if (x.Context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/images/"))
                    {
                        using (var sr = File.OpenRead(path))
                        {             
/// Here I need to replace the original stream with the stream from the sr.
                            x.Context.Response.Body = sr;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked...

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = x =>
            {   
                if (x.Context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/images/"))
                {
                    using (var sr = File.OpenRead(path))
                    {             
                        HttpResponse hr = x.Context.Response;
                        hr.ContentLength = sr.Length;
                        sr.CopyTo(x.Context.Response.Body);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```